# Multidimensional scaling pseudo-code

Tags: algorithms, multidimensional-scaling

I am planning to write a program that performs MDS. Any pointers to where I can access the pseudo-code for MDS?
Thanks!

Comment: what is a pseudo code?

Comment: @EDi http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode

Comment: Try [Wikipedia page about MDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling), especially the "External links" section.

Answer (score 8):

There are different kind of MDS (e.g., see this [brief review](http://forrest.psych.unc.edu/teaching/p208a/mds/mds.html)). Here are two pointers:

- the [smacof](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/smacof/index.html) R package, developed by Jan de Leeuw and Patrick Mair has a nice vignette, [Multidimensional Scaling Using Majorization: SMACOF in R](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/smacof/vignettes/smacof.pdf) (or see, the *Journal of Statistical Software* (2009) 31(3)) -- R code is available, of course.
- there are some handouts on [Multidimensional Scaling](http://forrest.psych.unc.edu/teaching/p230/p230.html), by Forrest Young, where several algorithms are discussed (including INDSCAL (Individual Difference Scaling, or weighted MDS) and ALSCAL, with Fortran [source code](http://forrest.psych.unc.edu/research/alscal.html) by the same author) -- this two keywords should help you to find other source code (mostly Fortran, C, or Lisp).

You can also look for "Manifold learning" which should give you a lot of techniques for dimension reduction (Isomap, PCA, MDS, etc.); the term was coined by the Machine Learning community, among others, and they probably have a different view on MDS compared to psychometricians.

Answer (score 5):

If you have the Statistics Toolbox in MATLAB you can read the source code of `mdscale.m`. While it's not pseudocode, it will definitely help you understand MDS better and gives you one approach to coding it.

In MATLAB you can type

`edit mdscale`

and that will open up an editor window that shows you the `mdscale.m` script that does the work. If you don't have MATLAB, check out [Scikits.learn](http://scikits.appspot.com/learn). It has some code for MDS. A lot of times reading Python code is very similar to reading pseudocode!